# How to create one row sql result for below table data and condition

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ID Name Action Starttime Endtime
 1  APAC    INST_GEN    30-JAN-19 12.20.48.237000000 PM 30-JAN-19 12.21.45.111000000 PM
 1  APAC    RESULTS_GEN 06-FEB-19 08.34.58.824000000 AM 06-FEB-19 08.35.22.694000000 AM
 1  APAC    ACCEPT_SUBMIS   30-JAN-19 03.55.56.837000000 PM 
 1  APAC    RESULTS_PUB 12-FEB-19 09.36.43.500000000 AM 12-FEB-19 09.37.36.950000000 AM
 1  APAC    TPL_PUB 30-JAN-19 12.22.37.820000000 PM 30-JAN-19 12.24.40.747000000 PM
```

How do i output in one single row that if action= ACCEPT_SUBMIS then return oepn in submission column

Comment: SELECT CASE WHEN action = 'stuff' THEN 'open' END submission

Comment: SELECT CASE WHEN action = 'stuff' THEN 'open' END submission  returns 4 rows with not complete and 1 with completed status

Comment: i want only 1 row saying complete if it finds ACCEPT_SUBMIS entry

Comment: I suggest you see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)
 and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What is the "submission" column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WHERE` condition of you want to output a single row, e.g.:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Action, Starttime, Endtime, 'OPEN' AS submission 
WHERE Action = 'ACCEPT_SUBMIS';
```

Comment: i want to return 'open' if action = 'ACCEPT_SUBMIS' else close if action != 'ACCEPT_SUBMIS' in submission. how do i do that

Comment: But then, you will not get `only one row`. Do you need multiple rows?

Comment: NO I WANT ONLY ONE ROW. Thats the issue

Comment: Do you want only one row per id?

Comment: Yes, only one row per id